# Mobile Site for a large Background Image Site

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have a large Image Background Lead Generation Page http://minkstock.com

I want to make it Mobile Compatible but dont want to load the huge image which i use for the background on the desktop and tablet website.

Which is the best way to prevent it from loading on the mobile.

Comment: css media queries -> different stylesheets with different images set as background

Comment: @kirilloid since i am setting the image to reset to full length i am using this method http://paulmason.name/item/full-screen-background-image-pure-css-code

Comment: Just a little note: On the home-page signup form, you have `Emaill Address` with two Ls :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@devundef was right. We usually call background images from CSS. In this case CSS3 Media Queries were enough. I would also suggest to follow this rule.

Optional (if you don't want to adopt css background):
Have you ever checked **Foresight.js** plugin? It detects browsers along with the data network: https://github.com/adamdbradley/foresight.js

It gives you an option for adaptive image replacement according to user's browser and connection type. Good thing is you dont have to remove your background either and will able to keep consistency on UI.

Answer (score 2):

You can use css media queries.

Example:

```
// this background will apply only for screen sizes between 320 and 480px
@media only screen 
   and (min-device-width : 320px) 
   and (max-device-width : 480px) {
     background-image: none; // or another image...
}
```

More info:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: since i am setting the image to reset to full length i am using this method paulmason.name/item/full-screen-background-image-pure-css-code

Comment: So? You can still use it, but put that css rules inside a media query that matches with large screens, and use another media query for small screens and define another backgroung image for it...

Comment: i am using the image as an img object in the html.

Comment: Humm, I see. You'll have to change that, since it's not possible to change the src of an image using css. The best way I can see is create versions of common sizes (widths: 800, 1024, 1280, 1400) and also versions for small screens and then set the background via css. You'll need to create one media query for each width (using max-device-width: 800px, then 1024 etc.)

Answer (score 2):

As @devundef suggests, you can leverage media queries. However, your base implementation should be for the mobile experience with media queries to override the background with the full sized image.